# Generate points on a circle with fixed Euclidean distance [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab

I want to generate `n` equidistant points on a circle. The Euclidean distance between any two adjacent points is a fixed`x` units.  if I increase `n`, the Euclidean distance should still be `x`. That means the radius of the circle has to increase. However, the catch here is that the radius of the circle should be a multiple of `10` only.

So far I have come up with this code but I cannot figure out how to maintain the Euclidean distance to `x` and to keep the radius a multiple of `10` only when `n` is increased.

```
    r                   =  50; % radius
    NumCNs              =  100; % number of points
    dd                  =  r*exp((0:1/(NumCNs-1):1)*pi*2*1i)'; % location of the points
    XCor                =  real(dd);
    YCor                =  imag(dd);
    plot(XCor , YCor , '*');
```

If it is impossible to meet both criteria at the same time, then the Euclidean distance has to be maintained no matter what.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points will form a regular convex polygon. The radius of the circumscribed circle is given by equation `r=x/(2*sin(pi/n))`, where `n` is the number of points, `x` the distance between points and `r` the radius of the circle.

You cannot always meet both criteria at the same time, thus you should use this equation to compute the radius of the circle.